# How to fix errors preventing some .obj files from importing into Blender?

Tags: objects, add-on, import, error

Whenever I import simple clothing objects into Blender, there are no problems.
However when attempting to import certain other objects, the import fails and there are these errors...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\IMPORTANT DOWNLOADS FROM C DRIVE\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\__init__.py", line 147, in execute
    return import_obj.load(context, **keywords)
  File "D:\IMPORTANT DOWNLOADS FROM C DRIVE\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 1133, in load
    if strip_slash(line_split):
  File "D:\IMPORTANT DOWNLOADS FROM C DRIVE\blender-2.78c-windows64\2.78\scripts\addons\io_scene_obj\import_obj.py", line 852, in strip_slash
    if line_split[-1][-1] == 92:  # '\' char
IndexError: list index out of range

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

The only difference I can tell in the objects that fail and the ones that succeed is that the ones that fail seem to be more intricate. I'm using Blender 2.78c. I've tried other versions of Blender such as 2.83 and get the same results. Does anyone have a clue to what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: It seems that your .obj file is malformed or there is a bug in the importer. Please test with the [latest Blender release](https://www.blender.org/download/) and if it still fails, create a bug report through *Help > Report a Bug* in Blender. Please prepare a *minimal* example .obj (small file size) that fails to import and attach it to your report. The issue appears to be similar to https://developer.blender.org/T83671

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply.
I think you're right about the .obj being malformed.
I tested it in the latest version of Blender also and the result was the same.
The .obj was created in Marvelous Designer and that's where the problem is occuring.
The object was a hoodie. I deleted a zipper and it still did import into Blender, but after removing the pocket, I was able to successfully import the .obj into Blender.
The same thing resulted with the other .obj files; after removing a certain part of the object, they successfully imported. Again, thanks for the reply.